# How to assign Images url (dynamical ) to particular emp id's image view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage, imageurl

I have a `UITableviewCell` in that cell  I have added `name`, `emp_id`, and `UIImageview` to display the data I have 2 url's in which one url has displaying names and `emp_id's` and another Url have images along `emp_id's`(same emp_id's )  and I have to show that images to there names using help of `emp_id's`. I am able to show details but not able to implement the images here is my code

```
struct jsonstruct5:Decodable {
    var name:String
    var emp_id:String
    var url:String?
}

struct jsonstruct21:Decodable {
    var url:String?
    var emp_id:String
}

var arrdata = [jsonstruct5]()
var arrdata1 = [jsonstruct21]()



func getdata(){
    let url = URL(string: "https://sp/company/employees_detail/app")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        do{if error == nil{
            self.arrdata = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonstruct5].self, from: data!)

            for mainarr in self.arrdata{
                //              print(data)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            }

        }catch{
            print("Error in get json data")
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

Response is

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Sonu",
      "emp_id":"01"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Prasanth",
      "emp_id":"02"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Patra",
      "emp_id":"03"
   }.
]
```

```
func getdata1(){
    let url = URL(string: "https://sp/company/employees_detail/profile/photos")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        do{if error == nil{
            self.arrdata1 = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonstruct21].self, from: data!)

            for mainarr1 in self.arrdata1{
                //                    print(mainarr.name,":",mainarr.dob)
                              print(data)
                print(mainarr1.url)
                let data1 = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                print(data1)
                if let imageData = data {
                    let image4 = UIImage(data: imageData)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            }

        }catch{
            print("Error in get json data")
            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

Response is

```
[  
   {  
      "url":"https//ps/Image2",
      "emp_id":"01"
   },
   {  
     "url":null,
      "emp_id":"02"
   },
   {  
      "url":"https//ps/Image4",
      "emp_id":"03"
   }
]
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:AppreTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! AppreTableViewCell
    cell.nameLbl.text = "\(arrdata[indexPath.row].name)"
    cell.dateLbl.text = "\(arrdata[indexPath.row].emp_id)"
    print(DataManager.sharedInstance.empID)

    if (arrdata[indexPath.row].emp_id == DataManager.sharedInstance.empID)
    {
        cell.isHidden=true
    }
    else{
        cell.isHidden=false
    }
    //            tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
struct jsonstruct5:Decodable {
    var name:String
    var emp_id:String
    var url:String?
}

struct jsonstruct21:Decodable {
    var url:String?
    var emp_id:String
}

var arrdata = [jsonstruct5]()
var arrdata1 = [jsonstruct21]()

func getdata(){
    let url = URL(string: "https://sp/company/employees_detail/app")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

    do { if error == nil {
        self.arrdata = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonstruct5].self, from: data!)
        self. getdata1()
// don't for put reloadData in for loops, always play with your data/model and after loop you can call reloadData method.

    }catch{
        print("Error in get json data")
    }

    }.resume()
 }



func getdata1(){
    let url = URL(string: "https://sp/company/employees_detail/profile/photos")
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    do{if error == nil{
        self.arrdata1 = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonstruct21].self, from: data!)

// I don't know your model type, but you can put "url" from each iteration of second array (arrdata1) into first array (arrdata) where employee id matches.
// don't download images in below loop, rather download them in cellForRowAt method.
// then you just call self.tableView.reloadData()

// update your model
          for item1 in arrdata1 {
if let index = arrdata.index(where: {$0["emp_id"] == item1["emp_id"]}) {
        var item = arrdata[index]
        item["url"] = item1["url"]
        arrdata[index] = item
    }
}

// or below code
for item1 in arrdata1 {
if let index = arrdata.index(where: {$0.emp_id == item1.emp_id}) {
        var item = arrdata[index]
        item.url = item1.url
        arrdata[index] = item
    }
}


// model array has been updated, now work on cellForRowAt method

          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
        }

    }catch{
        print("Error in get json data")
        print(error)
    }

    }.resume()
}




 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell:AppreTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! AppreTableViewCell
let model = arrdata[indexPath.row]
cell.nameLbl.text = "\(model.name)"
cell.dateLbl.text = "\(model.emp_id)"

// here you download image for only current model.url
if let url = model.url {
    cell.nameOfImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(url, placeHolder: UIImage(named: "someImage")!, completionBlock: { (image) in
        cell.nameOfImageView.image = image
        })
}

//            tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
return cell
 }


let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

extension UIImageView {
    func loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(_ URLString: String, placeHolder: UIImage, completionBlock:@escaping (_ image:UIImage)->()) {
    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: NSString(string: URLString)) {
        self.image = cachedImage
        completionBlock(cachedImage)
    }

    else if let url = URL(string: URLString) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            //print("RESPONSE FROM API: \(response)")
            if error != nil {
                print("ERROR LOADING IMAGES FROM URL: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.image = placeHolder
                    completionBlock(placeHolder)
                }
            }
            else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let data = data {
                        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                            imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: NSString(string: URLString))
                            self.image = downloadedImage
                            completionBlock(downloadedImage)
                        }
                        else {
                            self.image = placeHolder
                            completionBlock(placeHolder)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        self.image = placeHolder
                        completionBlock(placeHolder)
                    }
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    else if URLString.isEmpty {
        completionBlock(placeHolder)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196640/discussion-on-answer-by-muhammad-waqas-how-to-assign-images-url-dynamical-to).